# One directive with two names in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a easy way to assign two different names to a directive?
Something like this:

```
app.directive(['directiveNameOne', 'directiveNameTwo'], function() {...});
```

I have a directive which handles radiobuttons and checkboxes the same way and I think it would be easier for other developers to have a unique wording for each element.

Comment: If both directives doing the same thing then there is no need of two directives. If both directives sharing the same logic but slightly differ in behavior then you better have a single directive and pass configuration via attribute `<directive type=radio></directive>` to adjust that behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no any alias notation. However you can provide the same configuaration function to both directives:

```
function directiveConfig() {
    return {
        link: function () { ... }
    };
}
directiveConfig.$inject = [];

app.directive('directiveNameOne', directiveConfig);
app.directive('directiveNameTwo', directiveConfig);
```

But having two directives that do exactly the same thing is probably not the best idea, it's confusing.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to avoid a long name like 'customRadiobuttonCheckbox', but using this code I would also have trouble with the attributes.